# combobox which filters dataprovider based on user input

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I need a combobox which filters dataprovider based on user input?

For example if user input is "CA" combobox will filter the dataprovider and show only data which starts with "CA". ("CANADA" and "CALIFORNİA")

note:combobox is editable.

and ı need this combobox in flex 3.

edit:okay ı got some help from javaluca and ı wrote this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" 
    creationComplete="createCompFonk()">
    <mx:Script>
     <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Text;
        import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
     import mx.controls.TextInput;
 import mx.events.ItemClickEvent;
 import mx.events.DataGridEvent;
 import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.collections.ListCollectionView; 
import mx.controls.ComboBox

     var sayac:int=0;
     var degisken:String;

     [Bindable]
     private var initDG:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([ {islem:'Tahsilat112', tarih:'01/01/2000', isim:'ATA'},{islem:'Ödeme', tarih:'02/03/2010', isim:'BETA'}      ]);




      public function createCompFonk():void{
        gggcombo.textInput.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, textChange);

      }
    protected function textChange(evt:TextEvent):void{
    (gggcombo.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).filterFunction = filterFunc;
    (gggcombo.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).refresh();
    // REFRESH IS NECESSARY
}

public function filterFunc(item:Object):Boolean{
    var pattern:String = gggcombo.textInput.text.toLowerCase();
    var string:String = item.islem;

    return pattern == string.substr( 0, pattern.length );
}
        ]]>
      </mx:Script>


  <mx:Panel x="0" y="0" width="435" height="216" 
      layout="absolute" title="Empty Default Datagrid">


   <mx:ComboBox id="gggcombo" dataProvider="{initDG}" labelField="islem" editable="true"  >


   </mx:ComboBox>
  </mx:Panel>


</mx:Application>
```

but ı got an error on these rows :

```
gggcombo.textInput.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, textChange);
```

and

```
 var pattern:String = gggcombo.textInput.text.toLowerCase();
```

Error is :
Attempted acces of inaccesible property textInput through a reference with static type mx.controls:comboBox

Comment: Try Klovis component about filter and autocomplete: http://lab.kapit.fr/default/klovis-kap-it-libraries/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ArrayCollection Class for combobox dataprovider, you can use the **filterFunction**.

Add listener on textInput that is contained into the combo

```
myCombo.textInput.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, textChange);
```

Function dispatched on the textChange

```
protected function textChange(evt:TextEvent):void{
    (myCombo.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).filterFunction = filterFunc;
    (myCombo.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).refresh();
    // REFRESH IS NECESSARY
}
```

FilterFunction for filtering dataProvider

```
public function filterFunc(item:Object):Boolean{
    var pattern:String = myCombo.textInput.text.toLowerCase();
    var string:String = item.name;

    return pattern == string.substr( 0, pattern.length );
}
```

Comment: thanks for help but when I try to run my app. I got an error on this row:                              var pattern:String = gggcombo.textInput.text.toLowerCase();   The error is:Attempted acces of inaccesible property textInput through a reference with static type mx.controls:comboBox

Comment: For the mx:ComboBox use gggcombo.text.toLowerCase();
The spark component have textInput property