# Filter/Search List box of Array Collection based on the user input text entered in the text area in Flex

Tags: javascript, java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a MXList Box having arrayCollection and I have another textarea box.

My requirement is: When users enter the desired text in the text area, I need to fetch and show the matching records from the List like:

```
___________
|____Ka___|    Text area
__________
|Kanrna   |List Box : ArrayCollection
|Kam      |
|Kao      |
|kaddsd   |So it looks something like this 
|_________|
```

I have tried with various approaches:

```
<mx:List id="availableProfileList"
    dataProvider="{campaignProxy.campaignWizardVo.currentProfiles}""/>

<mx:TextArea id="textSearch" textInput="applyFilter()"/>
```

```
protected function applyFilter():void{
    campaignProxy.campaignWizardVo.currentProfiles.filterFunction = matchingFunction(campaignProxy.campaignWizardVo.currentProfiles, textSearch.text);
    //Alert.show(textSearch.text)
    //availableProfileList.findString(textSearch.text);
    //availableProfileList.setFocus();
}

public function matchingFunction(availableProfileList:List, text:String):Vector.<int> {
             var results:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>;
             var item:String;
             var entered:String = text.toLowerCase();
           var itemIdx:int;
           Alert.show("before for");
           for(var idx:int = 0; idx < availableProfileList.dataProvider.length; idx++) {
           item = availableProfileList.dataProvider.getItemAt(idx) as String;
                 item = item.toLowerCase();
                 itemIdx = item.indexOf(entered);
                 if(item.indexOf(entered) > -1) {
                     results.push(idx);
                 }
           }
           return results;
             }
```

After checking these questions:

[combobox which filters dataprovider based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806821/combobox-which-filters-dataprovider-based-on-user-input)
and:

[Flex - Search/Filter DataGrid by Text Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039259/flex-search-filter-datagrid-by-text-input)

I still don't understand how to make it work.

Comment: Why the weird way with **filterFunction** (which you are doing in a wrong way anyway)? You can change the **dataProvider** directly from **applyFilter**.

Comment: I tried putting that logic in apply filter but still i didn't get it . If any hints are given , it will be helpful for me to implement

Comment: If this is a desktop application there is a great AutoCompleteComboBox component from Flextras that is doing exactly this: https://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&productID=19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mx:TextInput id="textSearch" maxChars="30" width="230" height="20.004135" change="applyFilter()" enabled = "true"
/>  


protected function applyFilter():void{
                    (availableProfileList.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).filterFunction = filterFunc;
                    (availableProfileList.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).refresh();
                }

public function filterFunc(item:Object):Boolean{
                    var searchedStr:String = textSearch.text;
                    var profile:ProfileVO = item as ProfileVO;
                    if (searchedStr == null) {
                        return (availableProfileList.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).refresh();
                    }
                    else {
                        return profile.profileName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedStr.toLowerCase()) == 0;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `availableProfileList.dataProvider as ArrayCollection` might throw a class cast exception. It would be better to cast via `as` and check if the result is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The **[filterFunction](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#filterFunction)** is a property of your **ArrayCollection** which should be set only once. Then.

```
<mx:List id="availableProfileList"
    dataProvider="{campaignProxy.campaignWizardVo.currentProfiles}""/>

<mx:TextArea id="textSearch" textInput="{campaignProxy.campaignWizardVo.currentProfiles.refresh();}"/>
```

The **filterFunction** must accept one argument that is supposed to be a collection item and return **true** if the item should be visible and **false** otherwise. The **refresh** method on data provider forces the filtering to happen.

```
function filterList(item:Object):Boolean
{
    // Returns true if item label (or title, or name, I don't remember)
    // starts with the text in the input area, case insensitive.
    return item.label.toLowerCase.indexOf(textSearch.text.toLowerCase()) == 0;
}
```

**DISCLAMER**: This all above is a guideline, not a complete solution, please figure details on your own.

Comment: Thanks Organis for the inputs , with the slight changes i made it working

Comment: And another query is how can i  filter the elements based on the keypressed on the list box . because keppress event is not there in list box so any pointers

Comment: @AvinashTS The **keyDown** event is perfectly there, inherited from **InteractiveObject**: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html#eventSummary

Comment: i am calling the below function with the list but i am able to capture only one character And first thing i want to know is is it possible to filter the list based on the user inputs at least 3 chars.   private function checkKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
 Alert.show("key"+String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
 }

Comment: @AvinashTS Unless these chars are kept for you, you need to manually keep the last 3 and invoke the **refresh()** so that it filters based on kept characters.

Comment: Sorry i am not clear about the solution, can you please brief me little more .

Comment: @AvinashTS If you want to filter the list by 3 last pressed keys, you need to keep these keys recorded. If user types in **TextArea** or **TextInput** - it is not a problem, UI keeps the typed text for you. If you want to filter your list with just keys pressed, and want more than one last key, you need to have some variable, where you keep track of pressed keys, right?